# Why the strapi admin panel may not open?

Tags: nginx, next.js, strapi

The Strap admin panel does not open. But the nextjs application received data from strapi. Nginx seems to be configured correctly.

[connetion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMren.jpg)
[config/server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXVsK.jpg)

I don't see any errors in nginx logs

nginx sites-available strapi config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.exemple.com;
    root /var/www/promo/nextjs-coupon/couponCMS;
    index index.js;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I changed the nginx config, but it didn't help